# Posting message on page wall (offline_access)

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post on my page wall through my app using PHP. I was using `offline_access` but now this is deprecated.

What I'm trying to do is each hour, I want to update my page with important information.

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) about the expiration of offline_access. It basically says that (once you set the advanced option `deprecate offline_access`) Server-side oauth will result in an access_token with a longer expiration date (60 days).

Please check if that's true, otherwise there's a url to exchange an access_token to one with extended expiration in the link above which you can try.

You will need to login to your app within 60 days to refresh the token.

---

Personally I don't know why Facebook thinks it will be great for developers (they say so at the bottom of the page), but what can we do?